# Android Studio 1.5.x for Mac is crashing randomly

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Android Studio 1.5 (AI-141.2456560) for Mac is crashing randomly quite often.

I'm using a Macbook Pro 15" Retina (mid 2105) and Mac OS X 10.11.1

It's really annoying. Have you experience these crashes? Do you know any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Here's the header of the crash log:

```
Process:               studio [42570]
Path:                  /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               1.5 (AI-141.2456560)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           studio [42570]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-12-22 12:17:05.252 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        AE86FBDD-3DF0-170B-2EDC-C5C7B67C46E0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1432CC7B-ECC1-4016-A467-1DD40780C49F

Time Awake Since Boot: 1000000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       420000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        25  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-000000010000b000 [   44K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

**EDIT**

1.5.1 also crashes all the time.

It's worth to mention that sometimes it crashes all alone without touching anything.

I've tried 2.0 Previews and they crash also but I think not so often.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem .... super annoying :(

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did not have a JRE installed. OS X Yosemite(10.10.5) drop it from a brand new install.
Just download here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with working with dual monitors on Mac. I have searched the internet and found some answers regarding the Emulator opening on the second monitor and making it crash. Try deleting the emulator .ini file from a hidden folder called .android, in the home folder of your Mac. This should sort of solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've working with devices (no emulator). I have to say that working with Android Studio 2.1 previews has reduced a lot the crashes now.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2.1 for Mac is the solution. No crashes at all with latest stable release: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/android-studio-21-supports-android-n.html

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. I am on 2.1 and still having the crash. Did you port over your settings for AS when you upgraded?

Comment: Yes @Elliott I ported over my settings. Now using Android Studio 2.1.1 without any crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have it installed on a M2 chip Max and it says startup failure and it’s been working. I am using it for homework.

Comment: Please use comment feature for such answers